# Nullability of reference types in value doesn’t match target type

Tags: c#

I'm having a play will nullable reference types and Entity Framework Core. The method should asynchronously return a nullable `User`, but the compiler complains

```
CS8619
Nullability of reference types in value doesn’t match target type.
```

The source code is as follows

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext DbContext;

    public UserRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public Task<User?> GetByEmailAddress(string emailAddress) =>
        DbContext.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress);
}
```

What is the correct way to write this code?

Update, I expect that having nullable turned on changes the meaning of `SingleOrDefaultAsync` to make it effectively mean `Task<{Non null user}>` so if I make my method async (like the following code) then the C# compiler will unwrap the `User` out of the `Task<>` and cast it as `User?`

```
    public async Task<User?> GetByEmailAddress(string emailAddress) =>
        await DbContext.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.EmailAddress == emailAddress);
```

Is there another way of doing this without having to make my method `async`?

Comment: Why is your User not already nullable? (Why did you declare that the method returns `User?`?)

Comment: is it perhaps that `IUserRepository` promises `Task<User>`, not `Task<User?>` ?

Comment: @CaiusJard I suppose OP is playing around with the new c# 8.0 feature nullable reference types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types

Comment: @MarcGravell - No, the method signature on interface is the same as the class. I've updated the question with more information that was quite interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is an issue as specified on Github for the Roslyn compiler:

[Allow null return from async method when `Task<T>` type argument is nullable](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/26667)